# How to print array variable with set_fact to use in ansible add_host module

Tags: json, elasticsearch, ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I am trying to dynamically build the inventory of an "elasticsearch" cluster using the add_hosts module.

I have these tasks:

In the first task (Identify ES nodes in cluster), I query the elasticsearch API to get the names of the nodes and save it in the "es_nodes" array

```
    - name: Identify ES nodes in cluster
      uri:
        url: http://localhost:9200/_nodes/_all/ip
        method: GET
        return_content: yes
        body_format: json
        failed_when: false
      register: es_nodes
```

In the second (Extract Node Names), I extract the names of the nodes and save them in a "nodo" array

```
    - name: Extract Node Names
      set_fact:
        nodo: "{{ es_nodes.json.nodes | map('regex_search', '([^\\s]+)') | select('string') | list }}"
```

And in the third (Create new var for IP Node), (I try, but I can't) get the IP using a loop with the names of the nodes. I manage to print the name of the variable "es_nodes.json.nodes. < nodo > .ip" but I cannot print the content, that is, the IP!

```
    - name: Create new var for Node IP
      set_fact:
        nodo_ip: es_nodes.json.nodes.{{ item }}.ip
      with_items: "{{ nodo }}"
```

In the verbose output show:

```
ok: [<ansible_ip>] => (item=GxcbPcQ0Qe6vSFOde0zFwg) => {"ansible_facts": {"nodo_ip": "es_nodes.json.nodes.GxcbPcQ0Qe6vSFOde0zFwg.ip"}, "changed": false, "item": "GxcbPcQ0Qe6vSFOde0zFwg"}
ok: [<ansible_ip>] => (item=V2bdDTnwTCexY67U36YE8g) => {"ansible_facts": {"nodo_ip": "es_nodes.json.nodes.V2bdDTnwTCexY67U36YE8g.ip"}, "changed": false, "item": "V2bdDTnwTCexY67U36YE8g"}
```

My final intention is to obtain an array with the IPs of the elasticsearch cluster "node_ip" to dynamically add them to the inventory with "add_hosts" and be able to work on the host group: "elasticsearch-security"

I imagine it would be something like this:

```
    - name: Add host to group elasticsearch-security
      add_host:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        groups: elasticsearch-security
      with_items: "{{ nodo_ip }}"
```

I would appreciate your ideas to know the correct syntax to print the IP and not the name of the node in the third task or a "different" way of doing the same to create the inventory dynamically.

Comment: in the nodo_ip fact, can you try this syntax : "{{es_nodes.json.nodes.{{ item }}.ip}}" ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Zebra8844

I try with your syntax, the verbose output said:

TASK [Create new var for Node IP] *********************************************************************************************************task path: config.yml:25
fatal: [<ansible_ip>]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected name or number. String: {{es_nodes.json.nodes.{{ item }}.ip}}"}

I think you can't nest keys inside keys

Comment: @Zebra8844 I try with this task:

`    - name: Create new var for Node IP`
`      set_fact:`
`        nodo_ip: "{{es_nodes.json.nodes.{{ item }}.ip}}"`
`      with_items: "{{ nodo }}"`

Comment: I tried with "{{es_nodes.json.nodes.[item].ip}}" and "{{es_nodes.json.nodes.['item'].ip}}" The answer is the same error.

Comment: Have you tried with {{item}} instead of [item] ?

Answer (score 0):

If I'll well understood, you need to build a variable from the content of another var (got from with_items) and then retrieve the contents of the variable.

One possibility is to create a separate playbook which will be included from the main script and use with_items on the include tasks.
Here is a simple example that you can adapt to your case:

Main playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    es_nodes_x: "val x"
    es_nodes_y: "val y"
  tasks:
    # Create new var for Node IP
    - include: sub.yml param={{item}}
      with_items:
        - "x"
        - "y"
```

Included playbook (sub.yml):

```
- set_fact:
    v: "{{param}}"
- debug:
    msg: "{{ vars['es_nodes_' + v] }}"
```

Comment: Thanks Zebra but, I tried this solution and in the sub.yml it does exactly the same, print the name of the variable but not its content

Comment: it's strange. I've run the above playbook on my computer and the debug msg prints the content of the variables, not the same. My ansible version is 2.5.1.